# Timer dispose in C#

Tags: c#, timer

If my class does not implement `IDisposable` interface, and if the class has a `timer` as an object what is the best way of disposing the `timer` as we can not dispose it in the class destructor, because the call to the class destructor is non deterministic?

Comment: "if my class does not implement IDisposable interface..." - if your class owns disposable resources, then not implementing IDisposable is the problem - you should.

Answer (score 5):

If your class uses disposable resources, your class should implement `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 3):

Any class which has disposable resources **should implement** `IDisposable` interface so that those resources can be properly released in `Dispose` method.

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    private Timer _timer = new Timer();

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //This way you can dispose your disposable resources used in class properly.
        _timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Timer` class is missing a `IsDisposed` property. There is a field variable `disposed`. With reflection you can then implement the `IsDisposed` property. This is needed because the Timer object is not set to `null` when disposed. If you then try to accidently Start the Timer again you get the message that its already disposed. With a check you can prevent this.

Why this could be a problem? When a Timer is implemented in a Windows Service this could be a problem. At some moments the Timer can be stopped and started again. But it should also be possible to Dispose the Timer. If the Timer is at that moment busy in a worker thread this can be a problem.